# Error in strtok function in C

Tags: c, strtok, string

I am using a simple program to tokenize a string using strtok function. Here is the code -

```
# include <stdio.h>
char str[] = "now # time for all # good men to # aid of their country";   //line a
char delims[] = "#";
char *result = NULL;
result = strtok( str, delims );
while( result != NULL ) {
    printf( "result is \"%s\"\n", result );
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
}
```

The program runs successfully. However, if line a is changed to

```
char * str= "now # time for all # good men to # aid of their country";   //line a
```

The strtok function gives a core dump. I would like to get an explanation for my understanding why this is so ? Because from the declaration of strtok as --char *strtok( char *str1, const char *str2 );  char *str as the first argument should work

Comment: Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays. You might like [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/), particularly section 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't modify a string literal. [The c faq on the subject](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html) explains it best. In a nutshell if you declare

```
char *stuff = "Read-only stuff";
```

You can't modify it.

The fact that strtok accepts a `char *` is related to the fact that **you can't pass arrays to functions**, you can only pass addresses. [Another c faq entry](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) might help here.

Answer (score 6):

`char *str = "foo"` gives you a pointer to a string literal (you should really be doing `const char *`, but C allows non-`const` for backwards compatiblity reasons).

It is undefined behaviour to attempt to modify a string literal.  `strtok` modifies its input.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers give the required answer, however additional info: You may want to consider using strdup() to create a duplicate of the string, which you CAN then use in strtok().  Just keep a pointer to the original returned buffer, as you'll need to free() it when finished with as it's malloced.